# Find the number of ways of sorting the letters of the english alphabet

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

This was the question :

***Find the number of ways of arranging the letters of English alphabet given that for any sequence:***

1. **Both small and capital letters are allowed**
2. **Small and Capital letters are distinct entities**
3. **Repetition is not allowed**
4. **No letter occurs with its small or capital counterpart**
5. **All letters occur exactly once in sequence in either small or capital form**

***Find the number of arrangements if:***

i) **Sequence of letters matters(Permutations)**
ii) **Sequence of letters does not matter(Combinations)**

Finding permutations seems easy:

Sequence length is $26$ and no. of entities is $52$ such that same letters never occur together.

No of permutations $= 52 \times 50 \times 48 \times 46  \times \ldots \times 2$

However I could not think of a way to find no of combinations.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation for the number of possible permutations is correct.  Another way to do the calculation is to choose whether to use a capital or lower case letter for each of the $26$ letters, then arrange the $26$ selected letters, which can be done in
$$2^{26} \cdot 26! = \prod_{k = 1}^{26} (2k) = 52 \cdot 50 \cdot 48 \cdots 4 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 52!!$$
ways.

If we do not care about the sequence of letters, we merely need to choose whether a capital or lower case letter for each of the $26$ letters.  Hence, there are $2^{26}$ such combinations.

Answer (score 1):

For combinations you just need to decide for each letter whether you have the lower or upper case form.